# Docusign Authorization Code Grant RedirectURI not working

Tags: rest, angular, oauth, docusignapi

I am working on integrating Docusign Authorization Code Grant Authentication. I've gone into the demo admin site, created an integrator key, and created the initial authentication request which looks something like this: (this isn't actually mine but the demo one.)

```
  GET /oauth/auth?
  response_type=code
  &scope=signature
  &client_id=230546a7-9c55-40ad-8fbf-af205d5494ad
  &redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback
```

To test this I originally tried running it in Postman. I was getting docusign login site html code as my return so then I realized this needs to run in the browser. I ran the URL and got to the docusign login page. I logged in but then nothing happened. I was expecting the browser to then be redirected to my redirectURI. Instead I was just sitting at the docusign user homescreen as if I went to docusign.com and logged in. Either the redirect isn't happening or I'm not setting this up properly. I am making sure the redirect URI in the integrator key admin page is the same as the one I am putting in the URL.

Questions:

- What is the HTTP call of the redirect URI? Is it just a GET call in the browser as if you were typing the URL in and going to the site?
- I tried different types of redirectURIs. I tried `http://localhost:3000/somepage` and `http://localhost:54326/api/callback` to test both my local site (Angular4) and my API without any luck. Also tried a random site like `https://www.yahoo.com` but the browser never redirected and the code in those locations wasn't hit.

How do you handle the redirectURI?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I forgot to use the auth server url instead of the rest api url. This is what the first authentication code request should look like:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code
  &scope=signature
  &client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  &redirect_uri=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

then when you enter your credentials, the browser will redirect you to your redirect_uri and the code you need will be in the URL

Comment: Hi Kevin, But can you please suggest me how you are doing it using code, as it will be an automated process, how can we logged in. I also get the html page of login in response of the above url from code.